# Changing format of output text file

Tags: python

I have a text file like this:-

```
V1xx AB1
V2xx AC34
V3xx AB1
```

Can we add `;` at each end of line through python script?

```
V1xx AB1;
V2xx AC34;
V3xx AB1;
```

Comment: Do you want to create a new file, or write it to existing file?

Comment: I want to write it in the existing file....

Comment: new file is also OK, as long as it has all the data

Comment: Yes, it's trivial to add a semicolon to each line and write it to a new file. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: What problem are you facing? You can iterate over all lines, add a `;` to them and append to a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can try. I have `overwritten the same file` though.

You can `try creating a new one`(I leave it to you) - You'll need to modify your `with` statement a little : -

```
lines = ""

with open('D:\File.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        lines += line.strip() + ";\n"

file = open('D:\File.txt', "w+")
file.writelines(lines)

file.flush()
```

**UPDATE**: - For **in-place modification** of file, you can use `fileinput` module: -

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('D:\File.txt', inplace = True):
    print line.strip() + ";"
```

Comment: Fileinput module supports  in-place modification of file allthough appears that the OP is looking to have things served up on a platter

Comment: @cravoori Thanks for the information. Can you take a look at my added code. Is it correct way of doing it?

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was using perl and that too worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
input_file_name = 'input.txt'
output_file_name = 'output.txt'

with open(input_file_name, 'rt') as input, open(output_file_name, 'wt') as output:
    for line in input:
        output.write(line[:-1]+';\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Open the original file, and create a blank file in write mode
File     = open("D:\myfilepath\myfile.txt")
FileCopy = open("D:\myfilepath\myfile_Copy.txt","w")

#For each line in the file, remove the end line character,
#insert a semicolon, and then add a new end line character.
#copy these lines into the blank file
for line in File:
    CleanLine=line.strip("\n")
    FileCopy.write(CleanLine+";\n")
FileCopy.close()
File.close()

#Replace the original file with the copied file
File = open("D:\myfilepath\myfile.txt","w")
FileCopy = open("D:\myfilepath\myfile_Copy.txt")
for line in FileCopy:
    File.write(line)
FileCopy.close()
File.close()
```

Notes: I have left the "copy file" in there as a back up. You can manually delete it or use os.remove() (if you do that don't forget to import the os module)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was using perl and that too worked as well.